# How to convert from ARGB to hex aarrggbb?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I tried using this code:

```
string ToHtml(System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        return string.Concat("#", (color.ToArgb() & 0x00FFFFFFFF).ToString("X8"));
    }
```

but System.Media.Color doesn't seem to have a toargb() method. I then tried with this code:

```
string ToHtml(System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        return ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);//.FromHtml("#FFDFD991");
    }
```

but ColorTranslator doesn't exist in windows phone. Can someone help me???? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Have you tried doing it per-component and cating the strings?

Comment: You can concatenate the result of `ToString("X2")` of _each_ component of the `Color` together.

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks!!! I am not very confortable with hex (i don't like it) so i didn't knew this trick.

Comment: Well, in your example you already have `X8` as a format string - this isn't much more of a stretch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return string.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}",
                     color.A,
                     color.R,
                     color.G,
                     color.B);
```